# Sending Data in chunks in Spring boot and angular application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a question that deals with the application design/architecture.

We have a UI Application that is developed in angular and the Java backend which is developed on Spring boot.

Now in one of the scenarios when the data is huge we want to break the data from the UI and send them in chunks to the spring boot backend and similarly also send data in chunks from backend to UI.

Can anyone please tell me the best way to achieve this.

Thanks!